# Overflow images in y index only

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a mini-gallery of images which I want to use to toggle content depending on the image clicked. When hovering on the image it scales up slightly. My problem is that when scaling I want to hide the overflow off the page but still show the overflow in the y-direction. I have tried overflow-x: hidden, overflow-y: visible but the y-overflow only appears at the bottom and scrollbars appear.

```css
#images {
        height: 70vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: visible;
    }
    #images .image {
        width: 50%;
        height: 35vh;
        transition: 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #images .image:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #images .image img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="images">
       <div class="image">
          <img src="image.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="image">
          <img src="image.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="image">
          <img src="image.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="image">
          <img src="image.jpg">
       </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to make these act as it would with no overflow stated without a scrollbar appearing in the x direction?

Comment: Can you provide us a working example in snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove overflow css from the images and add it to the body:

```
body {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add scaling property to image instead of outer div.

```css
#images {
        height: 70vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: visible;
        
    }
    #images .image {
        width: 49%;
        height: 35vh;
        transition: 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
    #images .image:hover img {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    #images .image img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="images">
       <div class="image">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000000">
       </div>
       <div class="image">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000000">
       </div>
       <div class="image">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000000">
       </div>
       <div class="image">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/000000">
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the image to scale over the surrounding images not just zoom in inside it's own box.